# paths and relative homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm unsure about my proof of problem 3.2(i) in Rotman's Algebraic Topology text.

## Problem

[image]

Note on notation: $I = [0,1]$ and $\dot I = \{0, 1\}$.

## Claim 1: $f'$ is continuous

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $e^{2 \pi i t} \in S^1$. Then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$
|f'(e^{2 \pi i t}) - f'(e^{2 \pi i s)}| = |f(t) - f(s)| < \epsilon \tag{1}
$$

if $s \in (t - \delta, t + \delta) \cap I$

Define
$$ 
\delta' = sup_{s \in (t - \delta, t + \delta) \cap I} |e^{2 \pi i t} - e^{2 \pi i s}| 
$$

Then (1) holds if $|e^{2 \pi i t} - e^{2 \pi i s}| < \delta'$. It follows that $f'$ is continuous. $\square$

## Claim 2: $f(0) = f(1) = x_o = g(0) = g(1)$ and $f \simeq g~\text{rel}~\dot I$ implies that $f' \simeq g'~\text{rel} \{1\}$

Let $F : f \simeq g~\text{rel}~\dot I$ and define $h : S^1 \rightarrow I$ by

$$
h(e^{2 \pi i t}) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}~e^{2 \pi i t} = 1 \\
t & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Define $G : S^1 \times I \rightarrow X$ by
$$ G(s,t) = F(h(s),t) $$
Then one can easily verify that $G(s,0) = f(h(s)) = f'(s)$ and $G(s,1) = g'(s)$. Also

$$ G(1,t) = F(h(1), t) = F(1,t) = f(1) = f'(1) = g'(1) $$

It follows that $f' \simeq g'~\text{rel} \{1\}$. $\square$

## Claim 2 v2

Let $\phi : S^1 \xrightarrow\sim I/ \dot I$ be the homeomorphism of $S^1$ onto $I / \dot I$. Define $h : I / \dot I \rightarrow I$ by

$$
h([t]) =
\begin{cases}
t & \text{if}~t \in (0,1) \\
1 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Then if $(a,b) \subset I$, $h^{-1}( (a,b) )$ is open in $I / \dot I$ because $(a,b) = \pi^{-1}(h^{-1}( (a,b) ))$ is open in I, where $\pi$ is the natural map $I \twoheadrightarrow I / \dot I$. Thus, $h$ is continous.

We will apply the result in Problem 3.1 to complete the proof:
[image]

$f \simeq g~\text{rel}~\dot I$ and $h \circ \phi \simeq h \circ \phi~\text{rel}~\{1\}$ imply that

$$
f' = f \circ h \circ \phi \simeq g \circ h \circ \phi = g'~\text{rel}~\{1\}
$$

## Update

- added Claim 2 V2 on 11/23
- Please point to errors in any section of my proof! This includes the original Claim 2, because I'm not sure where there error is if any.

Comment: $$S^1\cong I/\dot{I}$$

Comment: @FShrike: thanks! Can you point to any errors in my proof?

Comment: Do you know the concept of quotient maps?

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, for example the projection of $I$ onto $I/ \dot I$.

Comment: Do you also know that closed maps are quotient maps?

Comment: Surely closed maps aren't generally quotient maps...did you mean that? I think I understand the hint about using the quotient map for I. Let me think on this for a bit!

Comment: Please see my update -- again it would be extremely helpful if people pointed to specific errors in the proof, so I have a chance to correct them. Thanks!